# intersection of sets in C++

Tags: c++

i am trying to do simple sets intersection , it works correctly , but when output comes , it shows only memory address or garbage random value , help me ,i applied breakpoints , but it's not working . actually i am new in C++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class set
{
private:
    int size;
    int *elem;

public:
    set()
    {
        size = 0;
        elem = NULL;
    }
    set(int s);
    ~set();
    set(set &s);
    set intersection(set A, int z);
    void inputset();
    void outputset();
};

set::set(int s)
{
    size = s;
    elem = new int[s];
}

void set::inputset()
{
    int i;
    cout << "Enter the set  Element" << endl;
    for(i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
    {
        cin >> elem[i];
    }
}
set set::intersection(set A, int z)
{
    int i, j, k = 0;
    set R(z);
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < A.size; j++)
        {
            if(elem[i] == A.elem[j])
            {
                R.elem[k] = A.elem[j];
                k++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return R;
}

set::~set()
{
    delete []elem;
}

set::set(set &s)
{
    int i;
    if(size > 0)
    {
        delete []elem;
    }
    size = s.size;
    elem = new int[size];
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        elem[i] = s.elem[i];
    }
}

void set::outputset()
{
    int i;
    cout << "The elements of new set is :  " << endl;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << elem[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}


int main()
{
    int x, y, z;
    char choice;
    cout << "Enter sizeof set A" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    set S1(x);
    S1.inputset();
    S1.outputset();
    cout << "Enter sizeof set B" << endl;
    cin >> y;
    set S2(y);
    S2.inputset();
    S2.outputset();
    z = x + y;
    set S3(z);
    cout << "Enter I for intersection" << endl << "Enter U for union" << endl << "Enter D for     difference" << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    switch(choice)
    {
    case'I':
        S3 = S1.intersection(S2, z);
        S3.outputset();
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Invalid entry";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's a `std::set_intersection` algorithm.

Comment: @chris ??? what u want to say ?? i am trying to make my own algorithm

Comment: Friendly tip, work on your styling :)

Comment: `using namespace std; class set {...};` is very bad. There is a `set` class in the `std` namespace.

Comment: @AbdullahObaidullah, I'm merely saying there's no need to reinvent it. You gave no restriction that you couldn't use standard algorithms and that's what you would use in real code.

Comment: You create your set `R` with a size equal to `x+y` but it may contain less than `x+y` elements after the intersection. Try setting `R.size = k` to reflect the actual number of elements inserted.

Comment: @Chris i dnt want to use built in functions , just a basic programm

Comment: @AbdullahObaidullah: whts wrng w/ usng blt in fn's?

Comment: because it is assignment of universty , and i actually i am new in C++ , so facing problem:-)

Answer (score 0):

Your copy ctor should be set(**const** set &s); instead of set(set &s); What you have is a ctor that accepts a reference to set, which is not a copy ctor. So compiler generates default one for you and you have issue returning object by value from method intersection()
Also please fix your code indent, it is not easy to read it.

Also remove following lines from your "copy ctor":

```
if(size>0)
{
    delete []elem;
}
```

You cannot delete that pointer, your object is not constructed yet.

Comment: it is still returning the same error , and my indentation was right , but in this forum , it changes its style

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to check intersections between two sets, if your sets are in arrays, I'd suggest looping one of them and have a check if it's in between the other:

```
for (int i = 0; i < element1_size; i++) {
  for (int u = 0; u < element2_size; u++) {
    if (element1[i] == element2[u]) {
      cout << "Intersection point : " << element1[i] << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i am applying the same check , but when i return R in main function , it doesn't print any values

Comment: Yup. That's the classic. What's the worst case runtime complexity, though?

Comment: @sehe, worst case complexity would be O(n^2) if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a map to keep track of the "intersected" elements in much more efficient way. Here is a snippet of what I have in mind:

```
std::map<int, int> m;
for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
  m.insert( std::pair<int, int>(elem[i], 1) );

for(int i = 0; i < A.size; ++i)
  if(m.count(A[i]) > 0)
    R.elem[k++] = A[i]
```

This way you avoid the nested for-loops, and will be able to compute the intersection with logarithmic time complexity.

Comment: This solution has no sense at all. The goal is to implement a set instead of using the standard set (std::set). If you need a std::map to implement the set, just use std::set.